# How to mock useState using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

**I am using Jest and react-testing-library in React application. I have to test following scenario -**

```js
function Parent () {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState(true)

    return (
        <Child setCountry={setCountry} />
    )
}

function Child () {    
    const handleValueClear = () => {
        setCountry(false)
        const data = {
            id : 'IND',
            name : 'India'
        }
        dispatch(handleCountryDetails(data))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onclick={handleValueClear}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**How to mock and test useState in jest ?**

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Anyway, I have created a basic example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-lib-example-ppy7vf?file=/src/App.test.js) - with-out Redux. The way you're testing with react-testing-library is a bit different compared to "classic" jest testing. You're not testing that the instance got the right state. Instead, you're testing that the user gets the correct display after an action. See [Guiding principle](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#guiding-principles).

Comment: @AWolf Thank you for your explanation. But I have to mock setCountry and need to pass it to the child component.

Comment: I've added two test cases to the Codesandbox. One is mocking `useState` similar to Evren's answer and the other is passing a mock `setCountry` function. Both will work but I'd prefer the direct testing of the child by passing `jest.fn()`.

Answer (score 2):

*Your component*

```
import React from 'react'

function Parent () {
    const [country, setCountry] = React.useState(true)

    return (
        <Child setCountry={setCountry} />
    )
}

function Child () {    
    const handleValueClear = () => {
        setCountry(false)
        const data = {
            id : 'IND',
            name : 'India'
        }
        dispatch(handleCountryDetails(data))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onclick={handleValueClear}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

*Jest file for Parent*

```
test('useState mock', () => {
   const initialState = true

   React.useState = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([initialState , {}])
   
   const wrapper = shallow(<Parent />)

   // In this point your state set and you can test the rest
}
```

Comment: For useState, I am getting following error -> setCountry is not a function (). useState is not mocked. How to debug this issue ?

Comment: Thanks @Evren this setup has finally worked for me. After plenty of different mock setups on StackOverflow this was the first implemention with success for me. I want one thingy mention. If there are several test boundled in describe fns etc. then probably better to wrap it in an own describe() and into `beforeEach(()=> { ... }` for any case not to break other tests states.